# React download current page content as PDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, frontend

Below is my React component where I am trying to download a paragrapgh content from current page as PDF. It is getting downloaded but when I open the file it says "Failed to load PDF document."

**Note**: I cannot use any third party libraries. it should be a custom one.

```
import React from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
    const handleDownloadPDF = () => {
        const content = document.getElementById('pdf-content').innerHTML;
        const filename = 'page.pdf';
      
        const element = document.createElement('a');
        const file = new Blob([content], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      
        element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        element.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
        document.body.removeChild(element);
      };
  return (
    <div>
      <p id="pdf-content">This is the paragraph content.</p>
      <i className="icon">Icon content here</i>
      <button onClick={handleDownloadPDF}>Download Text File</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

It would be great if anyone can help me on this issue. I cannot use any third party libraries like jspdf, html2pdf, pdf-lib etc.

The funtionality should be custom only.

Comment: may I ask why you can not use 3d party libraries? thats what they are there for.

To your question, you cant write html to a file and expect it to render as pdf. you will have to write an actual pdf file

Comment: bwright
The project I am working on has setup their own artifactory registry to install packages and we cannot add any new package to it

Comment: If you want to create a pdf without using any third party library, you have to do some server side coding for that. Use something like Puppeteer. And the method you have provided is generating a Blob object with the mime type 'application/pdf', but the content being passed is just plain text. PDF is a complex file format that can't be generated from plain text or HTML as is. The blob expects the data to be in a valid PDF format, which is why you're getting a "Failed to load PDF document" error.
so better is to find a way of installing some third party libraries for this like jspdf or pdf-lib.